# How to locate the file who handles submit button in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal 7, it's weird to me compared to traditional programming like native PHP, MVC frameworks, Node.js, .Net, etc. Please help me locate the file and/or function that handles the submit button. I have this tpl file already

```
<form id="com_id" method="post" action="">
...
<button type="submit" id="saveBtn" class="hidden btn-save" name="btnSave"><?php echo t('SAVE'); ?></button>
```

As you can see there's no value in form's action. In Laravel MVC, it's easy,

```
Route::get('/the_path', 'RoutinesController@theMethod');
```

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x

Comment: The problem with that is it's not understandable. Is there a tutorial that's more comprehensive? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules)

2.Create a form in it [example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/form-api/creating-a-builder-function-to-generate-a-form):

```
function mymodule_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
 //build your form using the form api documentation, linked example and your needs
}
```

3.Add validation for the form:

```
function mymodule_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
//your validation goes here
```

}

4.Add submit function to it

```
function mymodule_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
//do stuff on submit here
}
```

Not sure where you want to print it but you can always put it in a custom block and render it from there or attach it to a node using hooks (mymodule_node_view) there are many ways but if you need more details be specific and we will help you out and don't forget to turn the module on once you created it :)

UPDATE: If the form already exists use hook form alter:

```
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'your_form_ID') {
$form['#submit'][] = 'your_module_custom_form_submit';
}

function your_module_custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

//do stuff here on submit
}
```

Comment: I couldn't see the html, js, and css in there.

Comment: you need custom module to perform form alter:

function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'com_id') {
$form['#submit'][] = 'your_module_custom_form_submit';
}

function your_module_custom_form_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

//do stuff here on submit
}

Your form id is "com_id"